# @OneToMany targeting an unmapped class, but class is mapped

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm setting up spring security, yet when I define a @OneToMany relationship I get the error:

Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: loginApi.users.Users.roles[Security.Roleinfo]

I've already tried most of the answers on here,
yes, I am importing from javax.persistance
yes, @Entity is on top of each class

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {
    @Id
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private int curreventid;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private int points;
    private int phone;

        // problem part
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "usersrole", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "username")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "roleid")})
    private Set<Roleinfo> roles;
}
```

Here is the roleinfo class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "roleinfo")
public class Roleinfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int roleid;
    private String roletitle;

}
```

right now I'm trying to join my usersrole table which has two columns containing the username and that user's role (roleid) with the user table.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you provide configs you have for hibernate?

Comment: I just have a application.yml file, here is the jpa section:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        format_sql: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

Comment: Do i need a certain config for hibernate? I thought spring security would map the class if I put the @Entity annotation over it?

Comment: Why not follow a tutorial? https://hellokoding.com/registration-and-login-example-with-spring-security-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-hsql-jsp/

Comment: Enable DEBUG logging of org.hibernate in application.yaml it seams the entities are not scanned. look for `Managed classes names` in log

Comment: I am following a tutorial, https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=egXtoL5Kg08. I've also read up on hibernate but I can't seem to get past this issue(been trying for over 4 hours now)

Comment: Can you add targetEntity = usersrole.class attribute and check ?

Comment: I don't have a usersrole.class, usersrole is a table in my db. I created one to check and added the targetEntity attribute in @OneToMany but it still didn't work

Comment: Read this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-entity-classes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @JB Nizet, after reading the docs I realized my security package wasn't under my springbootapp package, meaning the user class was never scanned for the @Entity flag.